# Plotting partial sums of the fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

I need to find and plot the fourier series of $\sin^{2}(x)$. 
I know that the Fourier Series for this function is clearly $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2x)$ which is the reduction formula for $\sin^2(x)$. but now how do i find the first, 5, 10 ... terms of the partial some and plot them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: well well ... you must be very happy, because there are no such terms :)

Comment: seriously?? so the first 10, 100, 500 ... terms of the partial sum are all zero O.O ? i mean. what would be the answer to that. i got pretty confused :D

Comment: may be i forgot to add something, the interval is [0, pi]

Comment: yep!! only two terms exist. $a_0$ and $a_2$

Comment: hold on ... wait!!

Comment: something missing, right?

Comment: actually i don't get it. because the series is supoosed to converge more and more to the actual function, i think. so not having those terms... what exactly does it mean

Comment: on further consideration, i don't think $b_n$ = 0. clarify more pleaseee.

Comment: ... it converges, there is no sine term here, therefore $b_n = 0$

Comment: i did the integral, but i only got $b_n = 0 $  iff n = 2. otherwise i have terms present. precisely, these: 
$ 2cos(\pi n) \over {n^3 - 4n} $ for n != 2. on $(0, \pi)$. or is this wrong?

Comment: could you show your work?? I would like to comment on it. I think I should have been a little careful when you changed the interval :(

Comment: yeah sure. why not? 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi}(sin(x))^2 sin(nx)\,dx, = 1\2\int_{0}^{\pi} (1-cos(2x))sin(nx)\,dx, \\
\end{align}

Comment: then follows

$1\2{ \int_{0}^{\pi}sin(nx)\,dx - $ $\int_{0}^{\pi}sin(nx)cos(2x)\,dx} $

Comment: After that, the result above is got. i don't see any zeros popping up, am afraid :(( .
so, how can i plot these things. i really want to see the changes in graph due to the number of terms. can u help me with the overall thing? thanks :)

Comment: hmm ... I think you need, 
$$ \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \sin^2(x) \{ \sin(2nx) \, \mathrm{or}\, \cos(2nx) \} \, dx$$
from the definition that the Fourier coefficients in the interval L.

Comment: Check [this out](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSquareWave.html)

Comment: yeah, i left the $\frac{2}{\pi}$ out intentionally since it doesn't bring out the zero no matter what.
why is it $sin(2nx)$ ?

Comment: No ... I also meant the inner $(2nx)$, that will give you, that fourier expansion has only 2 terms, $\frac 1 2 \cos(2nx)$ will be first term.

Comment: now, i think am more confused :). so what is the final fourier expansion?

Comment: same lol :) ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: $1\over 2$ - $ 1\over 2 $ $cos(2x)$ right?

Comment: yep that's right ${{{}}}$

Comment: hey, i finally understand everything :)). thanks alot. it was me confusing myself here :D

Comment: you are welcome :)

Comment: hey, can you put this as an answer so i can accept it? it was corredt after all and i just learnt how to approve correct answers :).

Comment: sure if you insist :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourier expansion of $\sin^2(x)$ is $\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 2 \cos (2x)$ :D